# Accessing method inside of class A without instantiating or extending class A?

Tags: java

I'm running into a problem here. I want to access the method `toggleTimer()` inside of my `Elevators` class from my `Input` class. However, I have redefined `public Elevators()` so that it has arguments, and I think that is causing the problem. **I cannot extend nor instantiate the class** `Elevators` **without causing** `public Elevators()` to execute. Is there any way to access the method `toggleTimer()` without executing `public Elevators()`?

For example: When I try to create a new object of `Elevators`:

`Elevators e = new Elevators()`
`e.toggleTimer()`

However, creating a new `Elevators` object causes `public Elevators()` to run, which I don't want to happen.

Example 2:

`public class Input **extends** Elevators {`

I cannot extend the `Elevators` class without adding identical constructors to `public Input()`, which I do not want to do.

What I need is a way to access, from another class, the `toggleTimer()` method in class `Elevators` without calling `public Elevators()`.

`Elevators` class:

```
public class Elevators extends JPanel {

boolean toggleTimer = true;
private int y = 0;
private int elevatorDirection = 1;
private Color fillColor;
private static Timer timer;

public Elevators(Color color, boolean goingDown) {
    fillColor = color;

    if (goingDown) {
        y = 0;
        elevatorDirection = 1;
    } else {
        y = getPreferredSize().height - 120;
        elevatorDirection = -1;
    }

    timer = new Timer(20, new ActionListener() {
        @Override
        public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e) {
            y += elevatorDirection;
            if (y + 120 > getHeight()) {
                y = getHeight() - 120;
                elevatorDirection *= -1;
            } else if (y < 0) {
                y = 0;
                elevatorDirection *= -1;
            }
            repaint();
        }
    });
    timer.start();
}

public void toggleTimer() { //I want to access this method without executing public Elevators()
    toggleTimer = !toggleTimer;
    if(toggleTimer) {
        timer.start();
    } else {
        timer.stop();
    }
}
}
```

`Input` class:

```
public class Input {
boolean toggleElevatorButton = true;
JButton toggleElevators = new JButton("Click to stop elevators.");

public void changeToggleElevatorButton() {
    toggleElevatorButton = !toggleElevatorButton;
    toggleElevators.setText(toggleElevatorButton ? "Elevators enabled. Click to disable." : "Elevators disabled. Click to enable.");

toggleElevators(); //This is where I want to call the method from the Elevators class
}
}
```

Comment: I can't see where the toggleTimer variable is defined, does this code compile?

Comment: @RichardTingle I removed the variable for neatness, but I will add it back.

Comment: thanks, if its declared static or not is important (i.e. is there one and only 1 in your whole application)

Comment: Don't remove any code referenced from your code, please. Including elevatorDirection etc.

Comment: Toggle timer is not declared static, meaning that there is one per Elevator. Assuming this is correct you cannot just make the method static as River suggests. The constuctor sets up the class to be used, why do you want to skip it?

Comment: Also `timer` doesn't seem to be declared anywhere... Which could be problematic...

Comment: @RichardTingle The constructor, in my case, creates a new animation in my GUI. I don't want another animation, so I want to skip it.

Comment: I think you are missing on what an "instance" means. What does this class represent? Why does it extend JPanel? How many of these are supposed to be in your program? What does it mean to toggle a timer if it has never been created and started?

Comment: @Nick In that case you may have your Elevator class doing too many seperate things, split it up into smaller logical units so you can use each one independantly

Comment: Considering `timer` is `static`, I'd make `toggleTimer` static as well.

Comment: @River Just fixed. I had not posted it because I thought that the variables would create a mess.

Comment: If timer is static, then it has no business to be started from the constructor. This means that every time you are creating an animation, it creates a new timer, but you are only keeping a reference to the last one.

Comment: @RealSkeptic thanks, you just solved another problem I was having :)

Comment: Seriously, @Nick, your design is very problematic. I'm sure you'll keep running into problems if you don't understand why some fields are supposed to be static and some should be instance fields. You should consider which information is important to keep separate for each animation, and keep static only things that are common to all animations.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes you can! This is what [`static` Java methods](http://www.programmingsimplified.com/java/source-code/java-static-method-program) are for!

Simply make the `toggleTimer()` method static and call with `Elevators.toggleTimer()`.

Comment: True, if this is a good idea or not depends on what the OP is trying to achieve

Comment: This would allow to *call* the method – but it could no longer work, having no static Timer to work with.

Comment: @llogiq True, but I'm kinda assuming the OP actually wants a single `Timer` and just hasn't figured out all the associated requirements yet.

Answer (score 0):

Ah good question, you don't want to use inheritance here.  You actually want to use composition and static.  I would recommend rewriting as so:

```
public class Input{
   private Elevator elevator;
   ...
}


public Elevators(Color color, boolean goingDown) {
     public static void toggleTimer();
}
```

or if you want to be even more OO you make a Timer class such that an elevator has a timer e.g.

```
public class Timer{
    public void toggle(){...}
   ...
}

public class Elevator{
    private Timer timer;

   public Elevators(Color color, boolean goingDown) {
      timer = new Timer();
      ...
   }
    ...
}
```